# Get rand number from range

Tags: ruby, random

I want to take a sample number from this defined range of numbers.

```
def self.ipg_amount_range
  (1..1000000000000000).to_a.sample
end
```

But when I load the code it takes a lot of time to load the code.
Is there some way to speed up this code execution?

Comment: not a ruby guy but isn't  (1..1000000000000000) an array? if so what do you expect?

Comment: `rand(1000000000000000)`

Comment: @nafas: no, it's a range. But adding `.to_a` materializes it into an array.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ahh I c , thx for the tip mate

Comment: One may prefer to write `1_000_000_000_000_000` for readability or for brevity either `1e15` or `10**15`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `to_a` method takes a lot of time to generate the array, which you don't need.

Just use:

```
rand(1..1000000000000000)
```

Comment: Or even just `rand(1000000000000000)`.

Comment: @TomLord or `(1000000000000000 * rand).round` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: I don't see why would anyone ever want to use this form, when we have the former.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. In, say, javascript you don't have a choice, but here we do :)

Comment: @TomLord Technically it should be `rand(1000000000000000) + 1`